# SQL concatenate variable in a while loop

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have *n* number of `@BLOCn` variables.

Is it possible to concatenate a variable name so that one can use the loop counter as part of it? For example:

```
DECLARE @BLOC1 int, @i int, @MAX int, @QTY int;

SET @i = 1;
SET @MAX = 1;
SET @BLOC1 = 12;

WHILE @i <= @MAX
BEGIN
   SET @QTY = FLOOR('BLOC'+@i)
   ...
END

SELECT @QTY
```

So far, I'm getting this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'BLOC' to data
>   type int.

I'm basically looking for the SQL equivalent of Javascript's:

```
var foo = 'var';
var bar = 'Name';
window[foo + bar] = 'hello';
alert(varName);
```

Comment: You could only do that using dynamic SQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added some details above. How could I achieve that using dynamic SQL?

Comment: Instead of having `n` variables have a table variable with `n` rows. What are you actually trying to do? The code you have shown repeatedly assigning to `@QTY` and never using the assignment doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @MartinSmith the code above is a boiled down example of my problem.

Comment: And following your edit what are you **actually** trying to do? What do you need this for? You are asking about how to implement your proposed solution to something without telling us what the something is. There is no direct equivalent of that JS construct in SQL.

Comment: @greener . . . You can't do it for variables  When I originally read the question, I thought "variables" was just another word for "columns".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not be able to do what you are asking the way that you are trying. SQL Server has an `exec()` function and an `sp_executesql` stored procedure that can run dynamic SQL. However, they both create another context for running the command.

If you are willing to use a table variable to hold your `@BLOC` values you can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @BLOCS table(k int, v int);
DECLARE @i int, @MAX int, @QTY int;

SET @i = 1;
SET @MAX = 1;

insert into @BLOCS values(1, 12)

WHILE @i <= @MAX
BEGIN
   SET @QTY = FLOOR((select v from @BLOCS where k = @i))
   set @i = @i + 1
END

SELECT @QTY
```

Answer (score -1):

As Gordon Linoff said you can do this with dynamic SQL:

Here is the concept. This is fairly complete code but you will obviously need to tweek it to your requirements. I am doing a simple example of how dynamic sql works.:

Declare a variable to store your SQL in it:

```
 DECLARE @sql as varchar(max)
```

Then all you do is create a SQL statement but as a string like this. This will give you all your fields dynamically created:

```
declare @sqlcounter as int
declare @listofvariables as varchar(500)
set @sqlcounter =1

while sqlCounter <= 12
BEGIN
set @listofvariables = @listofvariables + 'BLOC' + @SqlCounter +', '
set @sqlCounter = @sqlCounter + 1
END

set @sql = 'select ' + @listofvariables + ' FROM tablename'

EXEC @SQL
```

**Now understand this was not meant to be a complete solution but rather an explanation of how dynamic SQL works and how it can be applied to your issue.**

In this case the SQL will now be:

```
SELECT BLOC1, BLOC2, BLOC3, BLOC4, BLOC5, BLOC6, BLOC7, BLOC8, BLOC9, BLOC10, BLOC11, BLOC12 FROM tablename
```

Hope this helps!